# getIntent() error in DatabaseHelper.java

Tags: android

I am trying to send a string from the MainActivity to DatabaseHelper. It will be used as variable for a query. The code below is from some tutorials online. However, getIntent() and getString() result in some error. Would there be any other way to solve this? Thanks.

In my MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onSerialReceived(String theString) {                            
    Intent sendStuff = new Intent(this, DatabaseHelper.class);
    sendStuff.putExtra("key", theString);
    startActivity(sendStuff);

    DatabaseHelper info = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    info.openDatabase();
    String data = info.getResChar();
    info.closeDatabase();

    serialReceivedText.append(data);                            
}
```

In DatabaseHelper.java, which extends SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Intent extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    // Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String value = extras.getString("key");
    }
}

public String getResChar() {
    String CharacterResult = null;
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT NAME FROM PRODUCT WHERE PRICE = 25", null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            CharacterResult = cursor.getString(0);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return CharacterResult;
}
```

Comment: It says: Cannot resolve method 'getIntent()' and 'getString()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot resolve the method `getIntent()` because it is only available to classes that are children of the Activity class. (SQLiteOpenHelper is not a child of Activity)

It cannot resolve the method `getString()` becuase you are attempting to call it on an Intent object when it is a method belonging to Bundle objects.

Additionally, you cannot use :

```
Intent sendStuff = new Intent(this, DatabaseHelper.class);
sendStuff.putExtra("key", theString);
startActivity(sendStuff);
```

because an Intent is used primarily to launch an Activity. Your DbHelper class is not an activity so `startActivity(sendStuff)` would raise a runtime error.

The easiest way for you to send a string would probably be like this:

in MainActivity: replace

```
Intent sendStuff = new Intent(this, DatabaseHelper.class);
sendStuff.putExtra("key", theString);
startActivity(sendStuff);
DatabaseHelper info = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

with

```
DatabaseHelper info = new DatabaseHelper(this);
info.setString(theString);
```

in DBHelper: remove the `onCreate()` method because it will not be called.
add a global string variable : `private String theString;`
and add a method to set the string.

```
public void setString(String str){theString = str;}
```

Answer (score 1):

getIntent() is an Activity method so it can't be used in a non-Activity class

Try this,

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context context;

    public DbHelper(Context context, String name, int version) {
        super(context, name, null, version);

        // Application Context
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String res = this.context.getString(String_resId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can't use intent for class which is not extends Activity Super class.If you want to pass your variable like string than you must pass it to its constructor.

i.e
**Step 1:DatabaseHelper.class**

```
class DatabaseHelper extends SqliteOpenHelper{

String query;

DatabaseHelper(Context context,String query){
  this.query = query;
}
```

**Step 2 :Pass variable to databasehelper from your class**

```
DatabaseHelper info = new DatabaseHelper(this,"Your Query");
```

Comment: Its okey my friend
Welcome

Comment: @Deanne really are u from Ateneo de Naga University??